# Server Name Indication support for java 1.6

Tags: java, sni

I want to add SNI support for my server build on java. After googling i found that java 1.8 have the support in Server side. Is there any library or patch to support SNI in server side for java 1.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created patch for JSSE to support SNI in java 7.
https://github.com/jvenugopal/jsse-sni-patch

Comment: Did you find any workarounds for Java 6?
Edit: Sorry, my question is from a client-side point of view

Comment: @Dinoo No. I dint find.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm trying to make some kind of a workaround using a proxy like Java 1.6 client <-> Java 1.7 proxy app <-> Server-requiring-SNI